# I am looking for temporal EHR dataset

Tags: data-request, medical

I am looking for temporal EHR dataset for my project work. I know some hospital website allows to download the dataset. But it requires permission and the dataset huge which will be difficult to manage. I am looking medium simple temporal EHR dataset. Could you give me link of the website.

Answer (score 0):

The freely available MIMIC dataset (https://archive.physionet.org/physiobank/database/mimicdb/) contains temporal EHR info.